# Different order depending on condition

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a 'product' table with 3 columns:

```
id (int)
priority (1 or 0)
price (int)
```

After I've ordered the products by priority desc, I would like to order the two subsets by price. the subset with priority = 1 by ascending price and those with priority = 0 by descending price.
I've tried things like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY priority DESC, CASE priority = 1 THEN price END ASC, CASE priority = 0 THEN price END DESC
```

but nothing I tried seemed to work.
Any idea on how to approach this?
TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `WHEN` in your `CASE` syntax. This works:

```
SELECT * FROM product
ORDER BY priority DESC,
CASE WHEN priority = 1 THEN price END ASC,
CASE WHEN priority = 0 THEN price END DESC;
```

Simpler way is to run two queries, one for each priority, and combine the result sets using `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE priority = 1 ORDER BY price ASC
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM product WHERE priority = 0 ORDER BY price DESC
```

Comment: It is possible to do this in a single query using conditional expressions, however, union is a quicker and simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer!

Comment: @Shadow Yes, you're right. It seems that it is possible to achieve this with order by and conditional expressions also. I'll edit my answer and add it as an alternative way just to demonstrate the correct syntax since Philip almost got it right in his question.